# Trying to get a background Image to remain 'static' across all monitor and device sizes

Tags: css

I found the below code on stack overflow and was hoping for some clarity. I am updating my portfolio page and wanted to put a landscape image background  but how it looks on my laptop (the way I want it to look) does not translate over to my second monitor which is much larger. If I were to implement something similar to the below code would this help alleviate the issue so I can ensure that my page is identical across all sceens?

```
.background-wrapper {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-image: url(https://psuk.s3.amazonaws.com/asset/p4/image/c3c59e5f8b3e9753913f4d435b53c308/Shaun/3040ce690fce2054c2011cf6d2f8b537.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    /* By defining this, your image _will_ be cut off when the screen is
     * wider than 1920px, but since you don't want to stretch this would
     *  happen anyway. */
    background-size: 1920px auto;
}
```

Comment: what is your goal? You want the background image to be as big as the monitor? also, could you provide an example how it should look?

Comment: Yes and for anything laid on top of the image to properly translate across monitor sizes. Stuff seems to slightly shift when moving from the monitor I wrote all the code on to a different monitor

Comment: I’ll throw up an example later today

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for a simple example of a fullscreen background image. You can edit the `min-height` value to get the effect you want.

Example: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/REzMZW

HTML:

```
<div class="full-home" style="background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800');" ></div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-home {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-position:50% 50%\9 !important;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```